# how to fix gulp watch Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected end of JSON input?

Tags: npm

`i tried 'gulp watch' and get the next error
i tried a lot of gulp modules install but it's didn't work for me.

this error:

```
intro gulp watch 
[21:57:46] Requiring external module @babel/register
ConfigError: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected end of JSON input
    at /Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/humy2833.ftp-simple/remote-workspace-temp/a951a47defbd38f00d74b15fdcb4b8b8/home/tendong/mmeta/intro/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/package.js:22:11
    at /Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/humy2833.ftp-simple/remote-workspace-temp/a951a47defbd38f00d74b15fdcb4b8b8/home/tendong/mmeta/intro/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/utils.js:22:12
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/humy2833.ftp-simple/remote-workspace-temp/a951a47defbd38f00d74b15fdcb4b8b8/home/tendong/mmeta/intro/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:21:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (/Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/humy2833.ftp-simple/remote-workspace-temp/a951a47defbd38f00d74b15fdcb4b8b8/home/tendong/mmeta/intro/node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
    at Function.sync (/Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/humy2833.ftp-simple/remote-workspace-temp/a951a47defbd38f00d74b15fdcb4b8b8/home/tendong/mmeta/intro/node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
    at sync (/Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/humy2833.ftp-simple/remote-workspace-temp/a951a47defbd38f00d74b15fdcb4b8b8/home/tendong/mmeta/intro/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:62:25)
    at sync (/Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/humy2833.ftp-simple/remote-workspace-temp/a951a47defbd38f00d74b15fdcb4b8b8/home/tendong/mmeta/intro/node_modules/gensync/index.js:182:19)
    at onFirstPause (/Users/macbook/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/humy2833.ftp-simple/remote-workspace-temp/a951a47defbd38f00d74b15fdcb4b8b8/home/tendong/mmeta/intro/node_modules/gensync/index.js:210:24)
```

and my node, gulp, npm version

```
➜  intro node -v
v16.19.1
```

```
➜  intro gulp -v
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

```
➜  intro npm -v
9.6.2
```

how can i resolve this error ?

i tried gulp and node version downgrade and reinstall node_modules

and this code is my gulpfile.babel.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOcxL.png)

Comment: As it throws error like **'Requiring external module @babel/register'**, may be you could try re-installing `gulp-cli` globally.